# stop a previous executed function after resizing $(window)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function and it will be triggered when the browser's width is larger than 1024px. But what should we do to terminate the function everytime when we resize the browser less than 1024px.

```
function abc(){do something}


$(window).resize(function(){
 var winWidth = $(window).width();

 if(winWidth >= '1024'){
   abc();
 }else{
   /////cancel abc()
 }
});
```

Comment: I assume abc() is recursive, otherwise it would run just the one time it is called from your resize handler and not need to be terminated separately?

Comment: If so, you may want to consider defining a boolean `var exceedsMinWidth` whose value is updated by the resize() function according to the logic you already have in place.  Then wrap the content of your abc() function in a conditional that checks against `exceedsMinWidth`.  Call abc() from the resize function only if `exceedsMinWidth` is `false` at the time resize() is called, otherwise your recursive function may be called multiple times w/o a terminating condition!  You may also want to look into [function debouncing](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).